# ng serve not detecting file changes

Tags: angular

ng serve (or ng build --watch) not detecting file changes

1. Generate a brand new project ng new project
2. Select scss and all other defaults
3. run npm start
4. any changes
   4.a change *.ts
   4.b change *.html
   4.c change *.css
5. save file